# How to redirect subfolders to read all codes from the main directory? similar source codes in subfolders but different contents

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, dns, subdirectory

I'm developing a website which has three sub folders in the main directory as `/a/`, `/b/` and `/c/`. Contents in main directory like `site.com`, `site.com/a/`, `site.com/b/` and `site.com/c/` are different; however, the codes and files are completely similar. In order to reduce the volume of the codes, I want to find a way to delete all code files in my sub folders and so all requests to be responded by the main directory files while I keep the sub folders. Could you please give me your opinion about changing the `index.php`, `.htaccess` or etc to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)/(.*) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will make all requests to `a/smth`, `b/smth`, `c/smth` be rewritten to `smth` (in the root directory) and `a`/`b`/`c` passed as query-string parameter 'folder'.

However, when you access static files like this, `a/image.png`, `b/image.png` (for instance) are still considered different uris - and as such will be downloaded separately by the browsers (instead of caching). So you should consider treating resources in a different way. for example, make a separate folder for static resources and address it directly from each subfolder.

For more information, read  [`mod_rewrite` manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure sure there is not .htaccess in `/a/` OR `/b/` OR `/c/` directories

Place this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[abc]/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```